# Why does my iPhone 4s resume playing a paused podcast after a missed call?

Tags: iphone, podcasts.app

Here's the sequence of events:

1. I'm listing to a podcast via the relatively new podcast app.
2. I pause the podcast.
3. Time passes. The phone sleeps.
4. I get a call which I do not pick up; I don't even touch the phone.
5. The podcast resumes playing, surprising me and those around me.

This would be expected behavior except for item 2. I think it's a bug.

I'm running iOS 6.0, but this has been happening for a while; at least since 5.something. It's possible that it began happening when I started using the new podcast app instead of the music app for podcasts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a bug they introduced in iOS6. drives my crazy.

Hope they fix it soon. No easy way to tell Apple they have a bug, unless you sign up to their developers program

Comment: To file bugs you only need the free developer account.